# How do I properly handle a success response in an ExtJS proxy?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have created a custom proxy with a custom reader and writer to interact with JSON documents in RavenDB. Loading and saving is all working well, except that the response for each update is not being handled properly. I can still see the red triangle (dirty?) in the corner of some grid rows after they have been successfully saved to the data base.

The response looks like this:

```
{Patched: true;}
```

I am familiar with the successProperty, but I am not sure if that relates here or how/where to set it. In the proxy? In the Model?

I suppose a less elegant solution would be to hook some event and call `commit()` on the record.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the proxy

```
proxy: {
    reader: {
        successProperty: 'Patched'
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. I tried it anyway and it did not work. If there was a success property on the writer, then it would make sense.

Comment: @Peter Li is correct, the correct way to do it is specifying the `successProperty` on the reader. It doesn't make sense on the writer, because you're reading a response that comes back from the server.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo. Does it return {Patched: true;}, not {Patched: true} ?

Comment: The short of it is that it did not work. Are you sure that the reader is what handles an UPDATE response?

Comment: Yeah. I am pretty sure about that. It successfully cleans the dirty marks for my grid. It may be wrong somewhere else in your store configuration. I can not tell since you didn't upload your code.